# When is it appropriate to change the original question?

Tags: discussion

**The Post**

[Can I animate rotateY() on an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907925/can-i-animate-rotatey-on-an-image)

**The Problem**

It took some effort to even suss out what the issue was.  I end up answering this question regularly, with varying degrees of success.

**The Question**

At what point do I start editing the question to something more SEO-friendly and in broader terms in the (perhaps somewhat futile) hope that a future user finds this answer rather than asking the same question again?

Comment: You can edit the question anytime, as long as you don't change the code (other than formatting). Preferably though, if you're answering the same question repeatedly, you should be voting to close as duplicates of one of those prior questions instead. There's no point in *answering this question regularly* - VTC the duplicates instead of doing so.